# Angular 2 pass array via @Input

Tags: angular

I'm trying to pass a simple array through an input to a component : [1,2,3,4,5]

For some reason it is not staying as an array but as a string when it passes through.

My type is @Input() data: any

Comment: It would be quite helpful if you would post the code that demonstrates how you pass the array ;-)

Answer (score 4):

If you use `prop="{{myArray}}"` bindings the value is stringified.

Use instead

```
[prop]="myArray"
```

Comment: Thank you sir, I will try that when I get back